# Calculating the second moment of binomial random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't understand how they got the equality E[Y+1]= np[(n-1)p+1].
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Yxs.jpg

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link

Comment: Note on the left hand side of your equation, you should have $\Bbb E(X^2)$. By the formula in the link, this is $np\Bbb E(Y+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you asked for is justified in the link as follows. $Y$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n_Y:=n-1$ and $p_Y:=p$. So, knowing that the expected value of a binomial random variable is equal to the product of it's parameters, i.e. that $$E[Y]=n_Y\cdot p_Y=(n-1)p$$ and by using the linearity property of the expected value, i.e. that $$E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$$ we have that $$E[Y+1]=E[Y]+1=(n-1)p+1$$

Comment: Is that what you was asking, or was your question why is Y+1 binomially distributed?

Comment: No that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, everybody just knows $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = n p(1+(n-1)p)$$

But if you didn't know that, you might check a reference and from the image you cite: $E[X^k] = npE[(Y+1)^{k-1}]$.  This means, $E[X^2] = npE[Y+1] = np(E[Y]+1) = np((n-1)p+1)$.  This last is from the sentence "... where $Y$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n-1$, $p$."

Comment: D'oh.  Redundant now.  Well done, Stefanos.